# SQL dates filter automatic time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a datetime column, and we need to run a query on it to look back for two years,

so I need to automate this:

```
where Appt_DateTime > '20140530' per the current date.

where Appt_DateTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 2 YEARS
```

the latter gives an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near 'YEARS'.

Comment: Please specify the SQL flavor used. There is no standard ANSI SQL function to do that. But in TSQL for example you can use `where Appt_DateTime > DATEADD(year, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2... all have a way to do similar thing but the syntax is different.

Comment: Then above mentioned SQL fragment should work.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis: there absolutely is a standard way of doing that: `current_timestamp - interval '2' year` but SQL Server doesn't support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DateAdd(YY,-2,GetDate())

```
... Where Appt_DateTime >=DateAdd(YY,-2,GetDate())
```

or

```
   ... Where Appt_DateTime >=cast(DateAdd(YY,-2,GetDate()) as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is mySQL 'YEARS' does not exist in mySQL syntax. Try 'YEAR'.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html